# JodaTime Period: Print first nonzero element

Tags: java, android, jodatime

Quick question that's been bugging me for a while. I need to calculate the time between two different DateTimes, then display only the largest unit of time for that Period. For example, if the time between two objects was 4h 55m 40s, I just want to print 4h. I can write a method that iterates through the getValues() method of the Period class, but array iteration is expensive and slow. Is there a stock way to do this, so I don't reinvent the wheel? Thanks.

EDIT: Here is my periodformatterbuilder method:

```
private PeriodFormatter createFormatter() {
    PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .printZeroNever()
    .appendDays()
    .appendSuffix("d")
    .appendSeparator(" , ")
    .appendHours()
    .appendSuffix("h")
    .appendSeparator(" , ")
    .appendMinutes()
    .appendSuffix("m")
    .appendSeparator(" , ")
    .appendSeconds()
    .appendSuffix("s")
    .toFormatter();
    return formatter;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get it to print nothing for hours if days aren't 0.

Comment: I think you need a PeriodFormatterBuilder, in particular the `printZero*` methods.

Comment: Which one would I use? All 3 have the same description in the API, and the names of the methods themselves don't explain much.

Comment: Your formatter seems to work for me, printing days, but not hours if days != 0 and hours == 0

Comment: Sorry, I should have explain myself better. What I want it to do is if (days!=0), print only days. If (hours!=0), print only hours. So that only the largest time duration is ever printed. Would this be possible with a formatter?